# the game UNO java code design

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, object

So for designing the popular card game "UNO" I have run into a problem where if the user inputs (-1) to draw a card from the deck and put it into their hand, im running into an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Now I know that it is because another element to the array isn't being created, but I'm not sure how to do so in this situation.

Here is my code for the addCardToHand method:

```
public void addCardToHand(Card c)

    {
        this.cards[this.cardCount] = c;
        this.cardCount++;
    }
```

This method intially works for getting the players 5 cards each, but that's all I have been able to do. It is being called by another method in a different class that generates the Card object parameter from the "top of the deck." What do I do next?

Comment: How big is the `this.cards` array?  Are you resizing it when it needs more space?

Comment: Thats actually what I figured I need to do but I'm not sure how to add another element! It's being initialized at 5, which is how many cards the person holds when the game starts

Answer (score 2):

Remember that simple arrays are not as dynamic as `ArrayList`s in that they don't automatically resize to accommodate more entries. You could either use an `ArrayList` or you could create a new array, larger than `this.cards`, and copy all of the values into it (including the new `Card` that you are adding), after which you would issue the statement `this.cards = newArray`.

Comment: yeah I'm trying to avoid the use of an ArrayList, but i think replicating the array might do the trick.

Comment: Yea that'll work - a simple <code>for</code> loop would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new array twice the size of the previous one whenever you can't insert a new card. That way you won't need to copy the whole array every time you add a card.

So, let's say you have an array a=[1,2,3] and you want to add a new card 4 but can't. You make a new array b=new Card[a.length*2], copy the previous values from array a, and put the 4 at the position you need. You end up having an array a=[1,2,3,4,-,-]. After adding 3 more cards you would have an array a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-,-,-,-,-], etc.